# Walking Sprite animation Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

I am new to cocos2D development. Basically I want to develop game in which i want to move sprite forward with walking kind animation, must look real. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: define "real" ..

Answer (score 1):

Basic sprite animation is really simple:

```
int frame_to_play = (game_tick * target_fps / tick_rate) % number_of_frames;
```

The result will tell you which frame (the `frame_to_play`-th) to show.

`game_tick` would be some kind of frame counter that just counts up (has to tick at least as fast as your animation is meant to be played).

`target_fps` is the framerate at which your animation should play (this must not be larger than `tick_rate`).

`tick_rate` is the amount of increments to `game_tick` per second.

`number_of_frames` is really just the number of frames in your animation cycle.

Note that this will create a linear/repeating animation (i.e. no partial loops or "ping pong" playback). If you want something else, you'll have to add some more logic.

How to make it look right/real? That once again requires some experimentation: Experiment with the speed your character moves (most likely something fixed/predetermined) as well as the framerate of your animation.